# Possible to make "paste in place" a default behavior?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to make "paste in place" a default behavior in Adobe software?

Comment: In illustrator just use the F or B keys rather than the V key to paste.

Comment: @Scott Expected that answer :) How to make this the default instead of some weird shortcut?

Comment: You can't unless you rewrite code in the application. But how is that weird? Rather than Command/Ctrl-v to paste... just use Command/Ctrl-f or Command/Ctrl-b

Comment: @Scott The current implementation doesn't make sense. Copy and paste are so universal and hard to remove from muscle memory.

Comment: Looks like you already know the answer :) Use CTRL+F, every professional in the world does it without overthinking this.

Comment: Ctrl-v does not paste stuff where i cut it out from in most applications but smack middle your cursor. Illustrator tries to follow that paradigm cursof being where you screen is located. Anyway you can change ctrl+v into paste in front if you wish in the shortcut editor. Anyway since you may need to be able to paste behind too then you still need a additional shortcut. You will learn in no time, if nothing is lost nothing will be gained. So i dont suggest you do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter keyboard shortcuts in many application. 
For Illustrator choose `Edit > Keyboard shortcuts`.

For my time, in **Illustrator**, I find just using the **default** Command/Ctrl-f or Command/Ctrl-b easier. In fact, they make more sense.. f = front, b = back. So I don't fully understand the "issue" you seem to have with this. "Muscle memory" is a really weak excuse in my eyes, especially since both the f and b keys are adjacent to the v key.

Comment: The statement above is not true, many apps lets you change their keyboard shortcuts. You can easily change the shortcuts in the 'Keybord shortcuts' menu of Adobe apps.
ctrl-shift-V is the default shortcut, swap it with ctrl-v and you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

VERY EASY. Edit the Keyboard Shortcuts to swap the behaviour.
This works for virtually all Adobe products.

Steps for Adobe InDesign:

1. Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Click "New Set..." (make a new keyboard set)
3. Name it whatever you like, based on [Default]
4. Product Area -> Edit Menu  (dropdown)
5. Under "Commands:", scroll to "Paste", and click on it
6. click into the "New Shortcut:" edit box
7. press "Shift-Ctrl-Alt-V"
8. click "Assign" button
9. Click on "Paste in Place" in the Commands section
10. click into the "New Shortcut:" edit box
11. press "Ctrl-V"
12. click "Assign" button
13. click "Save" button

done.